# After turning off the modem must juggle

Tags: 10.10, 3g

I have a Ubuntu 10.10, hooked 3G internet with no problems. Only one problem after disconnect from the Internet then no longer connects ... be able to pull out of the USB, then stick and then konektitsya normal. Is there any way to do something so that it was not necessary every time distorting the modem?

Comment: While you're welcome to ask for a workaround, you should also consider [Filing a Bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), after making sure it's not already been filed.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this bug. Tried it with two different modems. Every time the modem loses connection, you've got to pull it out, plug it into another USB port (which is kinda difficult with only two ports available) and then then you may reconnect.